# Amount of products per page in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

Dear fellow coders and community,

I have really researched this issue for quite a while now, and though I have some coding background, I can't seem to figure out the issue. No links to the topic helped since they all only suggest the code snippet I am using already.

I have a working **Word Press installation : Version 4.8.2 & WooCommerce : Version 3.3.5**

My Theme consists of essentially 2 Files, since I had to breakdown the whole thing in order to find the issue.

The **functions.php**

```
<?php

add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns');
if (!function_exists('loop_columns')) {
    function loop_columns() {
        return 5; // 3 products per row
    }
}

add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', 'new_loop_shop_per_page', 999999999999 ); 

function new_loop_shop_per_page( $cols ) {
  // $cols contains the current number of products per page based on the value stored on Options -> Reading
  // Return the number of products you wanna show per page.
  //
  var_dump($cols);
  $cols = 3;
  return $cols;
}

?>
```

The code is just supposed to limit the amount of products displayed on the product category page to 3.

And the **index.php**

```
<?php
get_header();
?>

<div class="container content pr-0 pl-0" >
  <div class="index">
  <?php  if ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
          <?php the_content(); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

This is just the essential index file needed by any wordpress installation.

Now I tried changing *backend settings* already with the default 2017 theme and it worked just fine...so it cannot be some backend thing.

What could be the issue here?

Any help or leads will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `loop_shop_columns` filter doesn't effect the number of posts shown, just the number of columns on the page (number of products going across before a new line is started).

The number of products shown on any page is actually taken from the WordPress Settings > Reading "Blog pages show at most" setting.

You can also change the number programatically by using the `pre_get_posts` filter.

Comment: Thanks so much! You made my day.

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'rc_modify_query_exclude_category' );
// Create a function to excplude some categories from the main query
function rc_modify_query_exclude_category( $query ) {
 // Check if on frontend and main query is modified
    if ( ! is_admin()  ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '-1' );
    } // end if
}

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'rc_modify_query_exclude_category' );
// Create a function to excplude some categories from the main query
function rc_modify_query_exclude_category( $query ) {
    // Check if on frontend and main query is modified
    if ( ! is_admin()  ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '-1' );
    } // end if
}
```

Comment: Glad to have helped. A warning though - `pre_get_posts` is very powerful and affects every single query, so you can have unintended consequences if you don't narrow down what you're affecting. `! is_admin()` is a starter, as it stops your function from running on the admin queries, but you should read the [Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) on the subject to target your function better.